# WKWebView appears with contentOffset scrolled if frame not set before load completes

Tags: ios, wkwebview

Using a WKWebView per Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) can lead to the WebView scrolled down depending if the content loads before the frame of the webView is set correctly.  This is especially apparent if you load a cached page.

```
override func loadView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    view = webView
}
```

This appears to be a known issue since iOS 9 http://www.openradar.me/22855188

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find any good references aside from the openradar report, but that remains a good solution.

Hopefully this can help someone else with the same issue.  **Set the frame** when creating the `webView` or assigning it to the `view`.

```
override func loadView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    // set the frame right away!!!
    webView.frame = view.frame
    view = webView
}
```

Comment: I have slightly different issue - but also related to the need to set frame, the view is offset down to some hundres pixels, this approach doesn't solve it, maybe anyone has other suggestion?